# Weakly lower semicontinuous functional on a bounded closed and convex set

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

Let $J$ be a sequentially weakly lower semicontinuous functional on $C$ with values on the real line. Moreover let $C$ be a bounded, closed and convex subset of a Hilbert space $H$.

Is it true that the functional attains his minimum?

Comment: $C$ is weakly compact. Forgetting everything else, we have a lower semicontinuous function on a compact set.

Comment: @DanielFischer: $J$ is only *sequentially* weakly lower semicontinuous, but this doesn't matter, since $C$ is also sequentially weakly compact.

Comment: @gerw I overlooked that word, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints for the proof:

- Define $j = \inf_{x \in C}J(x)$
- Take a sequence $\{x_n\} \in C$ with $J(x_n) \to j$.
- Find a weakly convergent subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ with limit $x \in C$.
- Proof $J(x) = j$.
- Conclude.

Comment: Thanks! It is the classical approach: construct a minimizing sequence.
So it is a generalized version of the extreme value theorem.

Comment: The proof is something like:
$$\inf J(x) \leq J(x*) \leq \lim \inf_k J(x_n_k) = \lim_n J(x_n) = \inf J(x)$$

But if the infimum is infinity the sequence $J(x_n_k)$ is not convergent and the last equality is not true. Am I wrong?

Comment: In case $j = +\infty$, you have $C = \emptyset$, which is not interesting. In case $j = -\infty$, you get a contradiction with $J(x) \le \liminf_{k} J(x_{n_k}) = j$. Hence $j \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think the problem is the double index: you have to write ``x_{n_k}`` instead of ``x_n_k``.

Comment: Do this mean that $\text{argmin}_{y \in M} \| x - y \|$ exists for all $x \in X$, where $M \subset X$ is *weakly compact*? Here, $X$ could be a reflexive Banach space. Or do we need $X$ to be a Hilbert space? (Given that, by [the Eberlein-Smulian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem), weak compactness and weak sequential compactness are equivalent in Banach spaces.)

Comment: @Ramanujan: Yes, a reflexive space is enough.